# Change width of each "panel of tiles" in Win10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

There are plenty of guides that show you how to change the width of the start menu. But it seems it only can grow or shrink in width from the size of each "panel" (or folder or column) of tiles.

For example, this is my start menu, and it has two "panels" of tiles -- each of which can fit 6 small icons, or 3 medium icons, or 1.5 wide and large icons.

[image]

Is there a way to resize one of the panels so it can take: 8 small icons, or 4 medium icons, or 2 wide icons?  Ideally a way to do this on a per 'panel' option.

Every attempt I have made to simply drag the start menu wider or shorter has done so one panel / column at a time.

Using Win10 Home, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I would love to know as well...  I'm actually looking to make my left "panel" only be as wide as 4 small tiles.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I realize this is three years later, but I found it when searching for how to do similar, and later learned how to do it.  Maybe I can help other searchers.)

This can be done, but it is not so simple.  Copy this to Notepad or similar:

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    Version="1">
  <LayoutOptions
    StartTileGroupCellWidth="8"
    StartTileGroupsColumnCount="2"
    FullScreenStart="false" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
      <defaultlayout:StartLayout GroupCellWidth="8">
        <start:Group Name="Productivity">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WindowsLive.Calendar" />
          <start:Tile Size="4x2" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.WindowsLive.Mail" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="2x2" Column="6" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
        <start:Group Name="Explore">
          <start:Tile Size="2x2" Column="0" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:Tile Size="1x1" Column="6" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
          <start:Tile Size="4x2" Column="2" Row="0" AppUserModelID="Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="7" Row="0" DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\OneDrive.lnk" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Save that into a file with the `.xml` extension, like `Layout.xml`, and put it somewhere easy to type, like `C:\Temp`.

Next, open PowerShell as Administrator.
Run:

```
Import-StartLayout -LayoutPath "C:\Temp\Layout.xml" -MountPath "C:\"
```

assuming you put the file in `C:\Temp`.

At this point that layout would apply to all users created after this point.  You probably want it to apply to your own user profile too.  The easiest way is to wipe your start menu.

Unfortunately the way to do that seems to change every year.  If you're on Windows 10 version 1809, run:

```
Remove-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\*$start.tilegrid$windows.data.curatedtilecollection.tilecollection'  -Force -Recurse
```

If you're still on 1709 or so, run:

```
Remove-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\Cache\DefaultAccount\$start.tilegrid$windows.data.curatedtilecollection.root' -Force -Recurse
```

(source: https://www.joseespitia.com/2019/03/13/how-to-reset-your-start-menu-layout-in-windows-10-1809/ )

After all that, either reboot, or kill the Explorer process with
`Get-Process Explorer | Stop-Process`

And here it is applied:
[image: screenshot showing Windows 10 Start Menu with two groups of width 8]

Note in particular the `StartTileGroupCellWidth="8"` in the XML.  Unfortunately I have not figured out how to change this per panel/group; it appears to be all-or-nothing, despite the separate `GroupCellWidth="8"` entry.  Also a size of only `4` does not seem to work.

Still, hopefully now you or anyone stumbling across this later can get the idea of how to use this template to make their own custom Start Menu layout file.  I tried to give a variety of sizes and types to help.

Bonus: To get the name of an app to put in AppUserModelID, run in PowerShell `Get-StartApps`

(I find `Tile` better than `DesktopApplicationTile` because it doesn't matter where the shortcut .lnk file is.  It also allows for 'placeholders' before the app is even installed.)

Comment: For some reason, I only just now saw this answer. Thank you for putting it together. I haven't tried it myself (sort of moved on from the problem) BUT, seriously, thank you for putting all those instructions together. As you said, it certainly isn't simple, but I suppose it's still a valid answer. So again, thank you!

Comment: Well thanks for coming back and saying so!  Indeed I assumed enough time had gone by, but figured I'd at least get the answer out there for future searchers.  Thanks for the accept.