# If you have pinned applications, can the Start Menu be made less wide than the width of the application list and three medium sized icons?

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu, resizing

On Windows 10, I have the list of application in my Start Menu. Next to that list, I have a 1 column wide and 8 rows long list of pinned applications. All of my icons are Small size. Despite this, my Start Menu refused to be resized to be less wide. I can make it wider, longer, or shorter, but not less wide. It's as if I'm forbidden from making it less wide than the width of my applications list plus the width of three medium sized icons. Is it possible to correct this without admin access to the machine?

From online research, I know that you can make the Start Menu match the width of your applications list by removing all pinned applications, but I very specifically want to keep my eight pinned applications.

Comment: The Start menu goes away as soon as you have made your selection (Windows 11 and 10), so it is easiest just to ignore it because it is gone before you know.

Comment: 1. Set it to hide when not in use. 2. Attach to left rather than bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for resizing the Start Menu are described in the article
[How to resize the Start Menu in Windows 10 (3 methods)](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-size-start-menu-windows-10/):

> Horizontal resizing is limited, as it only allows you to increase or decrease the size of the Start Menu pane by adding or removing lengths equal to the width of a [group of tiles](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-move-group-tiles-shortcuts-start-menu-windows-10/). Therefore, if you want to maximize the width, you need to increase the number of columns included in a group of tiles by choosing to [display more tiles in the Start Menu](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/more-tiles-start-menu-windows-10/).
> [...]
> the Start Menu resizes smoothly when it comes to its height, but it snaps into place to match the tile groups when you adjust its width.

Going by these rules, as long as you have pinned applications, they will
take up the width of one group of tiles and no less. The left part is
also not compressible and cannot be resized smaller than it already is.

See here the post
[Change width of each "panel of tiles" in Win10 Start Menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1089858/change-width-of-each-panel-of-tiles-in-win10-start-menu).

If this behavior is not to your liking, your only option is to file a
complaint with Microsoft on the Feedback Hub and hope that it gets
incorporated into some future release of Windows.

As the Windows Start Menu is not very flexible,
you may wish to try some Start Menu third-party alternatives.
For example, see the article
[Replace Your Windows 10 Start Menu With these Alternatives](https://geekflare.com/windows-start-menu/).
The most recent newcomer is not in the list :
[Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/)
(commercial).

Comment: And how wide is one group of tiles? Is it always, as I mentioned in the question, no less than the width of three medium sized icons?

Comment: It may depend on your icon sizes and the display settings. See also [Change width of each "panel of tiles" in Win10 Start Menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1089858/change-width-of-each-panel-of-tiles-in-win10-start-menu).